# Problems with creating a bar chart with more than one factor

Tags: r

I have again a problem with creating a bar char in R.

The dataset is now like this:

| Age | Season | Gender | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-15 | Fall | male | 60 |
| 10-15 | Spring | male | 80 |
| 10-15 | Summer | male | 100 |
| 10-15 | Winter | male | 50 |
| 10-15 | Fall | female | 60 |
| 10-15 | Summer | female | 50 |
| 10-15 | Spring | female | 40 |
| 10-15 | Winter | female | 50 |
| 16-30 | Fall | male | 60 |
| 16-30 | Spring | male | 80 |
| 16-30 | Summer | male | 100 |
| 16-30 | Winter | male | 50 |
| 16-30 | Fall | female | 60 |
| 16-30 | Summer | female | 150 |
| 16-30 | Spring | female | 40 |
| 16-30 | Winter | female | 50 |

Now I want to create a bar chart with this code:

```html
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x1 = Age,x2=Gender y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Season)
```

But I can't create a bar chart with gender and age in x-Axis and Season. A bar chart that shows gender and age and season.

Comment: You can do `dput(df)` in R so we can copy the data-frame creation code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is `fill` your age column in the bars using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = count, fill = Age)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Season)
```

Output:

[image]